# Redis connection errors (session handling)

Tags: magento2, session, magento2.4.3, redis

I am using Redis cache for session storage in my Magento `2.4.3-p2` based store.
The `app/etc/env.php` setting looks like

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
        'host' => '<private-ip>',
        'port' => '6380',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '2',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '3',
        'max_concurrency' => '12',
        'break_after_frontend' => '5',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '0',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
```

*Note: Redis is installed in a separate instance connected via private IP*

```
ps -ef|grep redis|grep -v grep

redis    20540     1  0 Dec07 ?        00:24:30 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
redis    25700     1  0 11:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 0.0.0.0:6380
```

And, I am frequently seeing the below errors in my server logs

1. Warning: `session_write_close()`: Failed to write session data using user-defined save handler. (session.save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions)
2. Connection to Redis : failed after 1 failures.Last Error : (1) Connection refused
3. read error on connection to :
4. LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory at

Redis (v6.0.9) installed on Ubuntu 18.04 instance has 32 GB of RAM and the settings look like this:

```
maxmemory:1gb
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
```

**New Relic graph**
[image: Redis Monitoring with New Relic]

Any idea what could be the reason? and some debugging tips/tools?

**EDIT**

Redis server logs

````
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.072 # Server initialized
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.072 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.073 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.9
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.073 * RDB age 1 seconds
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.073 * RDB memory usage when created 54.21 Mb
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.348 * DB loaded from disk: 0.275 seconds
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.348 * Ready to accept connections
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.348 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.348 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:signal-handler (1671738516) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # User requested shutdown...
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 * DB saved on disk
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 * Removing the pid file.
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
7901:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # WARNING supervised by systemd - you MUST set appropriate values for TimeoutStartSec and TimeoutStopSec in your service unit.
7901:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # Redis version=6.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7914, just started
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # Configuration loaded
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 6.0.9 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6380
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 7914
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.073 # Server initialized
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.073 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.073 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.9
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.073 * RDB age 1 seconds
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.073 * RDB memory usage when created 54.10 Mb
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.402 * DB loaded from disk: 0.328 seconds
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.402 * Ready to accept connections
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.402 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7914:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.402 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
````

Comment: Please post TEXT of your last 100 lines your error log for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck you mean the redis error log?

Comment: Any and all error logs you can put your hands on, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated the description with logs.

Comment: You may wish to take action on this suggestion from your error log posted for starters. 
    7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:47:06.072 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.